# Efficient way to compute sum of k largest numbers in a list?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, list, data-structures

I was reading some practice interview questions and I have a question about this one. Assume a list of random integers each between 1 & 100, compute the sum of k largest integers? Discuss space and time complexity and whether the approach changes if each integer is between 1 & m where m varies?

My first thought is to sort the array and compute the sum of largest k numbers. Then, I thought if I use a binary tree structure where I can look starting from bottom right tree. I am not sure if my approach would change whether numbers are 1 to 100 or 1 to m? Any thoughts of most efficient approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most efficient way might be to use something like [randomized quickselect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect). It doesn't do the sorting step to completion and instead does just the partition step from quicksort. If you don't want the k largest integers in some particular order, this would be the way I'd go with. It takes linear time but the analysis is not very straightforward. m would have little impact on this. Also, you can write code in such a way that the sum is computed as you partition the array.

```
Time: O(n)
Space: O(1)
```

---

**The alternative** is sorting using something like [counting sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) which has a linear time guarantee. As you say the values are integers in a fixed range, it would work quite well. As m increases the space requirement goes up, but computing the sum is quite efficient within the buckets.

```
Time: O(m) in the worst case (see comments for the argument)
Space: O(m)
```

Comment: If I do this with a BST, would I be looking at nlog(n) on average?

Comment: Yes, I think so. Assuming you construct a balanced binary search tree structure, each insertion would take approximately O(log n), and after it is built, you would have to sum over an entire subtree. A heap would be more suitable but still more complex than the above solutions.

Comment: In the counting sort alternative, shouldn't the time complexity be O(n+m)?

Comment: @EyalSchneider We look at each element (n of them), and put them in the appropriate mth bucket. I can't see how m would feature into time calculation though. Later, we read at most k of these buckets and k is strictly less than n.

Comment: @AnirudhRamanathan: At the second phase you scan the m buckets starting from the highest one. However, many of them may contain a count of 0, so in the worst case you have to scan all the m buckets.

Comment: I think maybe I misunderstanding your solution, if BST takes log(n), why wouldn't be preferable to your solution (O(n)), even with summing K integers?

Answer (score 3):

I'd say sorting is probably uneccessary. If `k` is small, then all you need to do is maintain a sorted list that truncates elements beyond the `k`th largest element.

Each step in this should be `O(k)` in the worst possible case where the element added is maximized. However, the average case scenario is much better, after a certain number of elements, most should just be smaller than the last element in the list and the operation will be `O(log(k))`.

Comment: "after a certain number of elements, most should just be smaller than the last element in the list" - I don't quite understand how that is true. Even in the average case, they are random numbers. Also, what sorting strategy would you suggest on the k-length list?

Comment: You don't need to sort. Just run a binary search to find the location of the next element in the array, then shift all the rest of the contents to the right, discarding the last one and insert your new element where it belongs. After a certain number of iterations, you won't need to shift most of the time because your lowest element will be higher than the average element in your random sample.

Comment: I see. What you describe sounds similar to [binary insertion sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort#Variants).

Comment: @AnirudhRamanathan Thanks. I knew there was probably a name for what I was describing, but I didn't know it.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use a [min-heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29) ([implemented as a binary tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap)) of maximum size k. To see if a new element belongs in the heap or not is only O(1) since it's a min-heap and retrieval of minimum element is a constant time operation. Each insertion step (or non-insertion...in the case of an element that is too small to be inserted) along the O(n) list is O(log k). The final tree traversal and summation step is O(k).

Total complexity:

`O (n log k + k) = O(n log k)`)

Unless you have multiple cores running on your computer, in which case, parallel computing is an option, summation should only be done at the end. On-the-fly-computing adds additional computation steps without actually reducing your time complexity at all (you will actually have more computations to do) . You will always have to sum k elements anyways, so why not avoid the additional addition and subtraction steps?

Comment: Does this have similar complexity to using a priority queue to keep a list of K largest numbers?

Comment: @user1529412 In http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue it says "While priority queues are often implemented with heaps, they are conceptually distinct from heaps. A priority queue is an abstract concept like "a list" or "a map"; just as a list can be implemented with a linked list or an array, a priority queue can be implemented with a heap or a variety of other methods such as an unordered array." So yes, it has the same complexity as *a common implementation* of a priority queue.

Comment: @Shashank You need to use min heap. Lets say 1,2,3,4,5 are the numbers and you need to find sum of 2 largest numbers. My initial min heap contains 1,2 when I read 3, I delete 1 and insert 3 now my heap becomes 2, 3. When I read 4, I delete 2, and insert 4. Now my heap is 3,4.

Comment: @Sandeep Hey, you are right. Using a min-heap, the comparison step is only O(1) to see if the next element belongs in the heap. And basically we keep the heap maximized at size k so insertion is average O(log k) with a binary tree implementation (worst case: O(n)). I understand your point and I've made the correction. Thank you. :)